# How To Filter Retrofit2 Json Response To Keep Only Certain Elements In ArrayList

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm new to kotlin so this maybe a very easy issue to resolve.

What I'm trying to do is filter the json response that I receive using Retrofit2 before I display the images in a grid with a RecyclerView.

`instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/?__a=1&max_id=` Using Retrofit2 I'm able to get the data response fine and also display the given url images in a RecyclerView.

I have not been successful in using the filter, map, loops and conditions to remove elements from the Arraylist. I do not understand these to the fullest extent but I have searched looking for solutions and those are what I came apon.

Interface

```
interface InstagramDataFetcher
{
    @GET("tags/{tag}/?__a=1&max_id=")
    fun getInstagramData(@Path("tag") hashtag: String) : Call <InstagramResponse>
}
```

Where I get my response from and also get StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
class InstagramFeedFragment : Fragment()
{
    private fun onResponse()
    {
        val service = RestAPI.retrofitInstance?.create(InstagramDataFetcher::class.java)

        val call = service?.getInstagramData("hashtag")

        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<InstagramResponse>
        {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<InstagramResponse>, t: Throwable)
            {
                Log.d("FEED", " $t")
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<InstagramResponse>, response: Response<InstagramResponse>
            )
            {

                //for ((index, value) in data.withIndex())
                if (response.isSuccessful)
                {
                    var data: ArrayList<InstagramResponse.InstagramEdgesResponse>? = null
                    val body = response.body()

                    data = body!!.graphql.hashtag.edge_hashtag_to_media.edges

                    for ((index, value) in data.withIndex())
                    {

                        if(value.node.accessibility_caption[index].toString().contains("text") ||
                            value.node.accessibility_caption[index].toString().contains("person"))
                        {
                            data.drop(index)
                        }
                    }

                    recyclerView.adapter = InstagramGridAdapter(data, parentFragment!!.context!!)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is my model class

```
data class InstagramResponse(val graphql: InstagramGraphqlResponse)
{

    data class InstagramGraphqlResponse(val hashtag: InstagramHashtagResponse)

    data class InstagramHashtagResponse(val edge_hashtag_to_media: InstagramHashtagToMediaResponse)

    data class InstagramHashtagToMediaResponse(
        val page_info: InstagramPageInfo,
        val edges: ArrayList<InstagramEdgesResponse>
    )

    data class InstagramPageInfo(
        val has_next_page: Boolean,
        val end_cursor: String
    )

    data class InstagramEdgesResponse(val node: InstagramNodeResponse)

    data class InstagramNodeResponse(
        val __typename: String,
        val shortcode: String,
        val display_url: String,
        val thumbnail_src: String,
        val thumbnail_resources: ArrayList<InstagramThumbnailResourceResponse>,
        val is_video: Boolean,
        val accessibility_caption: String
    )

    data class InstagramThumbnailResourceResponse(
        val src: String,
        val config_width: Int,
        val config_height: Int
    )

}
```

Simply again, I want to just remove elements from the arraylist that match certain things what I don't want. For instance. the "is_video" value that comes from the json. I want to go through the arraylist and remove all elements that have "is_video" as true.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you asking how to filter the list then below is the demo.
You just need to use `filter` on your `data` which is an ArrayList. I've tried keeping the same structure for the models so that you can get a better understanding.

```
    fun main() {
        val first = InstagramNodeResponse(
            title = "first",
            is_video = true
        )

        val second = InstagramNodeResponse(
            title = "second",
            is_video = false
        )

        val list: ArrayList<InstagramEdgesResponse> = arrayListOf(
            InstagramEdgesResponse(node = first),
            InstagramEdgesResponse(node = second)
        )

        val itemsWithVideo = list.filter { it.node.is_video == true }
        val itemsWithoutVideo = list.filter { it.node.is_video == false }

        println(itemsWithVideo.map { it.node.title }) // [first]
        println(itemsWithoutVideo.map { it.node.title }) // [second]

    }

    // Models
    data class InstagramEdgesResponse(val node: InstagramNodeResponse)

    data class InstagramNodeResponse(
        val title: String,
        val is_video: Boolean
    )
```